# Is there a way to put kibana dashboard png report in the body of the email

Tags: kibana

From the Documentation to generate email reports in Kibana using Watcher as attachments, but is there a way to add the PNG as part of the email? embedded image within the email body.

There seems to an option body.html, Has anyone used this?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions-email.html#email-action-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I case anyone else is trying to figure this ...

```
 "actions": {
    "email_report": {
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "attachments": {
          "weekly_report.png": {
            "reporting": {
              "url": "http://url.com",
              "retries": 10,
              "interval": "5m",
              "inline": true,
              "auth": {
                "basic": {
                  "username": "abc",
                  "password": "password"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "to": [
          "sm@email.com"
        ],
        "subject": "Daily - Monitoring Report",
        "body": {
          "html": "<p><b> Summary - 2 Week Trend <b><p> <img src=weekly_report.png>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer (S. Magesh) does cover the json for the watch, in 7.13, at least, you also need to tune the sanitization to allow inline img-s.

This is done in elasticsearch.yml with the following:

```
xpack.notification.email.html.sanitization:
  allow: body, head, _tables, _links, _blocks, _formatting, img
```

So,

```
1. <img src=your_image.png> in body.html on the watch
2. "inline": "true" under "reporting" on the watch
3. override default sanitization to allow img in elasticsearch.yml
```